Share dashboard with non-Salesforce users
We'd like to be able to share a couple of Salesforce dashboards with a client, but only a couple of dashboards; they don't need any other Salesforce access (they don't currently have any access at all), and we don't want to share anything else.
Is there an easy way to do this?

This is still an open Idea: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdWW0UAN/email-dashboards-to-nonsalesforce-users
The workaround is to have it emailed to you or another licensed user and then have an auto-forward from their email client to the end recipient.
Refer to this similar conversation on the trailblazer community:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A7OhvSAF
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A91omSAB

